# Reverse an Array of String in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to reverse an array of string in Objective-C.

I know there is a in built-method of doing it as follows:

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[inputString reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

but I want to implement same functionality with coding as follows and getting the following error.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

    NSMutableArray *inputString = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", nil];

        int lenArray= (int)[inputString count];

        NSMutableArray *reverseString=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:lenArray];

        for(int i=lenArray-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            [reverseString insertObject:inputString[i] atIndex:i];
        }
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   ' -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds for empty
>   array'

Comment: Have you tried to init your `NSMutableArray` without a capacity? It is not required and that may assist.

Comment: Why are you "insertObject" on reverseString? You're already going through the list backwards, you should just be addObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *inputString = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", nil];
      //  NSArray* reversedArray = [[inputString reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

            int lenArray= (int)[inputString count];

            NSMutableArray *reverseString=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:lenArray];

                for (int i = lenArray-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    [reverseString addObject:inputString[i]];
                }

               for(int i=0;i<=lenArray-1;i++)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@\n", [reverseString objectAtIndex:i]);
                }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`[reverseString insertObject:inputString[i] atIndex:i];` is the problem - specifically the `atIndex:i` part. You've created your mutable array with a large enough capacity, however it is still empty so specifying the index here is not what you meant to do.

Instead, just use addObject: `[reverseString addObject:inputString[i]];`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (int i = lenArray-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    [reverseString addObject:inputString[i]];
}
```

Note: Just use `addObject:` and change your for-loop condition to `i >= 0`, otherwise the "a" will be missing.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Jonahnnes, system does not allow me add another question. Sorry for bothering. I wanted to print the `reverseString` and typed the following code` for(int i=0;i<=lenArray-1;i++){printf("%s\n",[reverseString objectAtIndex:i]);}return 0;}}` but it prints the weird characters.

Comment: No problem. You are dealing with NSStrings. These are different from C strings. So you need to use different methods to print the string. Try either NSLog(@"%@", reverseString); or (in your for-loop) NSLog(@"%@\n", [reverseString objectAtIndex:i]);